# Groovy Script save domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I created the following script in the script folder using netbeans. I can't save the domain class. Also, if I deploy the entire project as a war file, can I run the script using Windows scheduler?

Script

```
def json = ""
def txt = new URL("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Singapore,Singapore&format=xml&num_of_days=1&key=b674fb7e94131612112609").text
def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(txt)
def weather = records.weather
def dates = weather.date
def min = weather.tempMinC
def max = weather.tempMaxC
def img = weather.weatherIconUrl
def desc = weather.weatherDesc
def descLink = desc.toString().replaceAll(" ","%20")
println max
Weathers w  = new Weathers()
w.cityName="singapore"
w.day = dates
w.description =desc
w.max = max
w.img = img
w.min = min
w.url = "jk"
```

Domain class

```
package org.mPest

class Weathers {
    int id
    String day
    String min
    String max
    String img
    String description
    String cityName
    String url

static constraints = {
    id(blank:false, unique:true)
    cityName(blank:false)
    url(blank:false)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use domain classes directly.

See [this FAQ](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20How%20can%20I%20access%20domain%20classes%20from%20sources%20in%20src/groovy?) to read how to use domain classes from `src/groovy`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
//…
def book = ApplicationHolder.application.getClassForName("library.Book").findByTitle("Groovy in Action")
```

I don't know if it possible to run the war packed script from windows but you could use the grails [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) to schedule your task...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`grails run-script` command](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html).  You should be able to use that to execute a script using something like windows scheduler or cron, but you'd have to have the full source code (not the war file) available for the script to execute with.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 2.x you should use Holders instead of ApplicationHolder. For example:

```
import grails.util.Holders
def validKeys = Holders.grailsApplication.getClassForName("com.vcd.Metadata").findAll { it.metadataKey }*.metadataKey
```